# Covariation of a gaussian process $ G_t = \int_0 ^t \frac{B_u}{u}du$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider $$ G_t = \int_0 ^t \frac{B_u}{u}du$$
where $\left(B_{t} \right)_{t\geq0}$ is $\mathcal F _t $ - brownian motian in $\mathbb R$, null at the origin. 
It's simple to show that $\left(G_{t} \right)_{t\geq0}$ is a centred gaussien process.

But, when it comes to the covariance evaluation, it seems we can find some probles with singularity at zero.

Someone could help me ?

Comment: Is the integral w.r.t. $du$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you Alex.

Comment: How did you prove that $G_t$ is well-defined (i.e. $u \mapsto \frac{B_u}{u} \in L^1[0,t]$)?

Comment: @saz [Local modulus of continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Modulus_of_continuity).

Comment: @did Thanks...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every nonnegative $t$,
$$\mathbb E(G_t^2)=2\int_0^t\int_0^s\mathbb E(B_uB_s)\frac{\mathrm du}u\frac{\mathrm ds}s=2\int_0^t\int_0^su\frac{\mathrm du}u\frac{\mathrm ds}s=2\int_0^ts\frac{\mathrm ds}s=2t.
$$
Likewise, for every nonnegative $s\leqslant t$,
$$\mathbb E(G_s(G_t-G_s))=\int_s^t\int_0^s\mathbb E(B_uB_v)\frac{\mathrm du}u\frac{\mathrm dv}v=\int_s^t\int_0^su\frac{\mathrm du}u\frac{\mathrm dv}v=s\log\left(\frac{t}s\right).
$$
Thus, for every nonnegative $s\leqslant t$,
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(G_s,G_t)=2s+s\log\left(\frac{t}{s}\right).
$$

Comment: Hello did! Could you expand or just explain me the argument to derive the very first equality? Thank you!

Comment: Sure: $G_t^2$ is an integral on $(u,s)\in[0,t]\times[0,t]$, which is twice the integral of the same function on $0\leqslant u\leqslant s\leqslant t$, by the symmetry $(u,s)\mapsto(s,u)$ and because the diagonal $0\leqslant u=s\leqslant t$ has Lebesgue measure zero..